# Is there a way to branch out duplicate usb information in android?

Tags: android

I use android 6.0 board and I want to connect two different usb device.

I used mik3y android serial usb lib.

The problem is both devices have exactly the same information(vendor id, product id).

How can I branch this devices?

I tried branch this by usb id but id is changed when reconnect device.

```
    LogUtils.d("USB connect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    List<UsbSerialDriver> availableDrivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(manager);
    LogUtils.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> USB size : " + availableDrivers.size());
    if (availableDrivers.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    int sensorIdx = -1;
    int ledIdx = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i<availableDrivers.size(); i++){
        UsbSerialDriver usbSerialDriver = availableDrivers.get(i);
        LogUtils.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>number : " + i);
        String str = String.format("====== [USB info] name : %s, product id : %s, vendor id : %s", usbSerialDriver.getDevice().getDeviceName(), usbSerialDriver.getDevice().getProductId()+"", usbSerialDriver.getDevice().getVendorId()+"");
        LogUtils.d(str);

        if(usbSerialDriver.getDevice().getVendorId() == 1027){
            sensorIdx = i;
        }
        if(usbSerialDriver.getDevice().getVendorId() == 6790){
            ledIdx = i;
        }
    }
```

This is log.
10-28 09:54:28.635 USB connect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
10-28 09:54:28.651 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> USB size : 2
10-28 09:54:28.658 ====== [USB info] name : /dev/bus/usb/001/020, product id : 24577, vendor id : 1027
10-28 09:54:28.664 ====== [USB info] name : /dev/bus/usb/001/013, product id : 24577, vendor id : 1027

Comment: It looks like the library does list two different physical USB device paths despite sharing the same VID and PID. So, you need to take into account the paths as well, not just relying on VIDs and PIDs. You can look into this sample USB terminal code that uses kai-morich fork from mik3y's [kai_morich/simple_usb_terminal](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleUsbTerminal/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/kai_morich/simple_usb_terminal/DevicesFragment.java)

Comment: Thank you. ecle I just solve this problem g_serial priorty.